# "Had changed destiny"

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, phrase-requests

I want to write something that means the same thing as "had changed destiny." I was going to use those words, but something didn't seem right. I googled that phrase, and came up with only one thing. So I don't think it's grammatically correct. Is it? What could I say that means the same thing?

Comment: You are going to have to give us more context if you want constructive answers.  Many people would not regard "destiny" as something that can be changed, for instance.

Comment: Like say someone is telling lots of lies, and they are enough to change someone else's destiny and make them go down the wrong road.

Comment: you mean like a fake astrologer?

Comment: @JoseK Simple untruthful word said in the right ear can destroy a kingdom you know. Without need for fake astrology :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your *had changed destiny* grammatically. IF you don't like the sound of it, rephrase. You can use *fate* instead of *destiny*, *altered* instead of *changed*, you can change the grammatical structure of your sentence (use passive voice for example)

> Someone's destiny was changed

Or there's another nice construction (don't remember it's proper grammatical name):

> Someone had his/her destiny changed

There are tons of other ways to say the same thing

> John's lies influenced Anne's fate.
>
> John loved lying, artfully altering the very fate of those listening to him with only words.

Comment: I think altered is a better verb for this for sure.